# How to get real Hexadecimal number from Hex as String

Tags: php

How do I get the proper Hexadecimal number from a Hexadecimal string?

For example:

```
<?php
$a = 'C8';
$b = 0xC8;
$c = doWhatHere($a);
$b === $c; // true
```

Comment: [`intval` accepts a base](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Comment: Please explain your problem clrearly

Comment: @GyandeepSharma how to I go from 'C8' to 0xC8. From C8 as String to 0xC8 as hex number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Ryan.

This does the Trick:

```
<?php
$a = 'C8';
$b = 0xC8;
$c = intval($a, 16);
$b === $c; // true
```